# Proxy is preventing my program from connecting to the internet

Tags: .net, proxy, networking, smtpclient

So I wrote this program to send a group of my friends a text message.
It works fine at home when I try to use it at work it doesn't work.  I get an error message "Failure Sending Mail".

We are using a intercepting proxy at work.  I though/hoped that everything would just work, clearly not.

So what do I need to do, I've never programmed to connect/send traffic through a proxy.

I'm using C# and the SmtpClient class to send the message.
Here's a little snippet.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(emailType.Address, emailType.Port);
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(tbxAccountUser.Text, tbxUserPassword.Text);
client.Send(message);
```

I talked to our IT department and I have the IP that they are using but I wasn't sure what I need.  I'm not even sure what class to use...

I tried this:

WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
        // Obtain the Proxy Prperty of the  Default browser.
        myProxy = (WebProxy)myWebRequest.Proxy;

```
        Uri newUri = new Uri("http://"+ ip +":8080");

        // Associate the new Uri object to the myProxy object.
        myProxy.Address = newUri;

        // Create a NetworkCredential object and is assign to the Credentials property of the Proxy object.
        myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWd);
        myWebRequest.Proxy = myProxy;
```

Im not sure if I can set this to my SmtpClient client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. The SMTP class doesn't have a proxy property, which makes things very complicated. The only thing that comes to mind is to use WebRequest class and to send every attribute of your mail message as a single string after which you wait for response by the server (WebRequest has a proxy property). But I haven't implemented it yet. :)